# WebGrid control issue in Mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, checkbox, webgrid

I am new in MVC and I'm trying to use WebGird control in my demo application I do some task like below:-

**HomeController**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Student> listStudent = new List<Student>();
            listStudent.Add(new Student { Id = 1000, Name = "Sumit Kesarwani", IsActive = true });
            listStudent.Add(new Student { Id = 1001, Name = "Arun Singh", IsActive = true });
            listStudent.Add(new Student { Id = 1002, Name = "Vijay Shukla", IsActive = false });
            listStudent.Add(new Student { Id = 1003, Name = "Pwan Shukla", IsActive = true });
            var data = listStudent;

            return View(data);
        }
```

**Student.cs**

```
public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcWebGrid.Models.Student>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    WebGrid webGrid = new WebGrid(Model);
}
@webGrid.GetHtml(columns: new[]{
  webGrid.Column("Id"),
  webGrid.Column("Name"),
  webGrid.Column("IsActive", header: "", format:@<text><input name="isActive" 
      type="checkbox" @item.IsActive == "true" ? "checked" : ""/></text>)
})
```

Above `WebGrid` will show all data in `readonly` mode, but I need those data will show in editable mode such as Id will show in Hidden field, Name will shows in `Textbox` and when data load `checkbox` will checked if its property have true value the `checkbox` will checked and if property have false value then `checkbox` will `uncheck`.

Please Please Please Help me!

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is my idea about your question

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcWebGrid.Models.Student>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    var webGrid = new WebGrid(Model);
    Func<bool, MvcHtmlString> func = 
    (b) => b ? MvcHtmlString.Create("checked=\"checked\"") : MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}

@webGrid.GetHtml(columns: new[]{
  webGrid.Column("Id" ,header: "", format:
  @<text>
      <input name="id" type="hidden" value="@item.Id" />
  </text>),
  webGrid.Column("Name", header: "", format:
  @<text>
      <input name="name" type="text" value="@item.Name"/>
  </text>),
   webGrid.Column("IsActive", header: "", format:
   @<text>
       <input name="isActive" type="checkbox" @func(item.IsActive)/>
   </text>)
 })
```

Comment: Sir I found a new problem related to 
Web-grid issue, I want to add a new row (dynamically) on a button click.

Comment: My solution is: 1- Enclose your grid with <div id="theGrid">...</div> 2- Set `ajaxUpdateContainerId: "theGrid"` in the Grid Constructor. 3- In every button click call the action, add new row in `listStudent` collection; it would be a clean solution without JavaScript coding. In this way you should store `listStudent` collection in a session variable. JavaScript solution might be better, but in the comment section I can't describe it to you.